# Rotating monitor for customers

Tags: monitors, pc, displays

Does anyone know of a good monitor that can be rotated easily for customers to see.  I know we have all seen the tablets that rotate at POS systems. Is there one that someone would recommend that just rotates to show the customer information?

Answer (score 1):

Many monitors have [VESA support](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_Display_Mounting_Interface), which is a standardization that allows 'universal' physical mounts to work. I am not aware of a standard monitor that rotates 180°, but many monitors (with VESA) can attach to a mount that supports movement like what you want.

-Mount (VESA 75x75 or 100x100): [https://www.amazon.com/MOUNTUP-Adjustable-4-4-17-6lbs-Computer-MU0004/dp/B07Z7ZGHD5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Z7ZGHD5)
-Monitor that could work, many can work, HP 21" with VESA 100x100: [https://www.amazon.com/HP-V223ve-21-5-inch-certified-Ergonomic/dp/B09GKZ71PJ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09GKZ71PJ)